# json file not found - issue when initializing gspread

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab, gspread, anaconda3

I am on a Mac Book Air mid 2013, macOS Big Sur 11.6.
My environment is JupyterLab 3.0.14, I access it through Anaconda.Navigator.

I want to read a Google Sheets file with Python using gspread.
I followed the steps shown here https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html#for-bots-using-service-account
All good until step 8. But then, there is an issue.

The code is the following:

```
pip install gspread
import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account()
```

And the error I have is: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/usuario/.config/gspread/service_account.json'

I tried to put the json file in another location (desktop for example and use in this case gspread.service_account(file name='~/desktop/credentials.json') but it keeps showing the error).

Full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b278ff01adee> in <module>
----> 1 gc = gspread.service_account(filename='/Desktop/credentials.json')

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/auth.py in service_account(filename, scopes)
    194     :rtype: :class:`gspread.Client`
    195     """
--> 196     creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_service_account_file(
    197         filename, scopes=scopes
    198     )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py in from_service_account_file(cls, filename, **kwargs)
    236                 credentials.
    237         """
--> 238         info, signer = _service_account_info.from_filename(
    239             filename, require=["client_email", "token_uri"]
    240         )

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py in from_filename(filename, require)
     70             info and a signer instance.
     71     """
---> 72     with io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as json_file:
     73         data = json.load(json_file)
     74         return data, from_dict(data, require=require)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Desktop/credentials.json'
```

Can you help please?
I would be very grateful, thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: have you checked this doc before? https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

Comment: @aberkb thank you for your comment, yes I used it as a reference...

Comment: Still need help on this issue, [gspread] people please show up, thank you